# How to call Post Methode from asp.net Web Api

Tags: c#, asp.net, api

I try to add data to my API with the HTTP Post method.

Here is my Controller:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class PostAccess : ControllerBase
{
    // POST api/<PostAccess>
    [HttpPost]
    public void Post(UserModel user)
    {
    }
}

public class UserModel
{
    public int UserID { get; set; } = 0;
    public string UserName { get; set; } = "";
    public string UserPassword { get; set; } = "";

}
```

And with this code, I try to add data.

```
        var postData = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>()
        {
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("UserName","Jeremia"),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("UserPassword","Jeremia")
        };

        var content = (HttpContent)new FormUrlEncodedContent(postData);
        await client.PostAsync("http://localhost:44355/api/PostAccess", content).ContinueWith(
            (postTask) =>
            {
                postTask.Result.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            }
           );
        }
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong.
I'm very frustrated because I search for 4 hours about this problem.

Sorry for my bad English, hope you have a good day :)

Comment: What is not working for you?

Comment: What's the issue you are facing?

Comment: Im Sorry for that missing information.

Comment: Sorry that is missed the information. I get this Expetion: HttpClient System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: 'The operation was canceled.'
When the client.PostAsync method is executed. And the Post Method on the other side (API) will not been called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you write the code that tries to add data in the Post function?

If yes you have to change the function to async by adding the keyword 'async'

```
public async void Post(userModel user)
```

Comment: I wouldn't recommend using `async void` for anything other than events

Answer (score 0):

thanks to mabruk for his answer!
Here is my working solution:

The Post Methode:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult<RequestModel<UserModel>>> PostUser(UserModel user)
    {
    }
```

And with Postman i send the HttpPost
[image: So you can reach the post Method]

If you want to send it by code, do it like this:

```
 private static readonly HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        var requestObj = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new UserModel()
        {
            UserName = "Jeremia1234",
            UserPassword = "9364"
        });

        var client = new HttpClient();
        var content = new StringContent(requestObj, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync("https://localhost:44355/api/GetAccess", content);


    }
```

And the RequestModel

```
public class RequestModel<RequestDataModel>
{
    public string JwtToken { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string UserPassword { get; set; }
    public RequestDataModel request { get; set; }
}
```